# Spring cloud stream 2.0 and startOffset latest

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

While upgrading our app to **spring boot 2.0.3** , we encoutered an issue with consuming messages and using `startOffset: latest`.
The scenario that we tested is as follows:

1. deploy an app with consumer(topic = TEST_CHANNEL,group = kafka2_test) configured with `startOffset: latest` to pcf and increase the number of instances to 5.
2. stop the app
3. publish 40 messages to TEST_CHANNEL topic
4. start the app

we can see that the app successfully assigns to the partitions ,however, some of the instances does not consume from the partitions that they are assigned to.
We also verified it by checking the lag for the group.
This scenario worked when using spring **boot 1.5.10.** It also worked when using **spring boot 2.0.3** and not setting the `startOffset: latest`.

**Note**: this is not a new group , so offset suppose to be present for the consumer to use, and `resetOffsets` should not have any effect.

Is this an issue in spring boot 2.0.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> not a new group ... and `resetOffsets` should not have any effect.

`resetOffsets` is specifically designed to reset the offset for an existing group to the `startOffset` value.

It was broken in the 1.3.x version of the binder (the version used by Boot 1.5.x) and had no effect.